# Can the doctor still save someone else if killed?

Tags: werewolf

In games that have more than one type of killer (werewolf, vigilante, hunter), what is the outcome if:

werewolf attacks villager, doctor heals villager, vigilante attacks doctor

Is only the doctor dead? Are both villager and doctor dead? Can the doctor heal the villager but then die later?

Hunters (shoots another player when killed) and vigilantes (hunts for werewolves) are not uncommon in the game, but I've never seen the issue of killing a doctor brought up in any forums.

In my version of the game, a vigilante dies of guilt if he kills an innocent, so in this scenario the villager, doctor and vigilante could all potentially die in one night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many variants of this game, and I can't find any place where rules state it (oficially) but there's no order when character's skills are played at night.
Doctor will save its target even if he's targetet by the werewolves/vigilante.

You don't need to look for a logical way of how does it happens, as it's not logical either a doctor healing someone from a werewolf attack (how is he supposed to heal someone ripped off?).

The only way of negating effects is with skills which state they negate the effect (some variations of the game include the escort, who stops someone from using his action that night).

Edit: in the scenario you proposed doctor would die but save the victim of the werewolf. Vigilante would die of guilt next day.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the variant you are playing.

Some the Doctor protects against all attacks. Some the Doctor protects against one attack. And others the Doctor only protects from werewolves. And still others have an order of operations so some attacks bypass the doctor while others don't.

**The Werewolves of Miller's Hollow:**

All healers, and defenders explicitly counter-act the werewolves (any werewolf); and no one else (Including the little girl if she is caught).

**Salem:**

Healers and defenders are order of operations. i.e. the jailer can stop all the mobsters from attacking before they can even choose and the mobsters know it; but a Serial Killer will kill both the doctor and the intended victim.

**Ultimate Werewolf:**

The Bodyguard defends from any killing. But the Leprechaun can only affect werewolf attacks.